# how can i get all the urls in chrome network by using python

Tags: python-3.x, web, python-requests

[image]

How can I get all the Request URL in chrome network

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a code/SQL/regex writing service, where you post a list of your requirements and language of choice and a code monkey churns out code for you. We're more than happy to help, but we expect you to make an effort to solve the problem yourself first. Once you've done so, you can explain the problem you're having, include the **relevant** portions of your work, and ask a specific question, and we'll try to help. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click -> Copy -> Copy all as HAR

Then you can import it like this:

```
import json
obj = json.loads(
'''
<paste here>
'''
)
```

You can then get `urls = [ entry['request']['url'] for entry in obj['log']['entries'] ]`

You may need to replace \" with \\" in your text editor for it to compile.